# TFS 2017 - Unable to create new branch

Tags: tfs

A few of my team members are unable to create a branch of the current Main branch inside the team project. I have made the user part of the Project Administrators group but he is still not able to do it.

There is no Deny rule active on the source or destination path that the user is a member of.

I have checked with tf vc perm /recursive and there is really no deny rule that should apply to him.

The user is receiving error:

```
TF14098 Access Denied: user Name needs Read permissions(s) for $/Project/Main/*.
```

The user works in the main branch daily and is able to checkout and checkin, the Project Administrators group has all permissions in the source control security overview.

I looked up the user in the project security overview and the user has the same permissions as i do, only "Manage project properties" is set to Not set, but this is for both of us.

I don't understand why this is happening, are there any others tools i can use to debug this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure you have set the `Manage branch` to `Allow` for TFVC (for git it's `Create branch`).

You can reference below screenshot to set the permission for the users.

If that still not work, then you can refer to below arcitlce for further troubleshooting, it's still apply to TFS 2017 although it's an old article:

[TFS Version Control Permissions – Why can’t I Branch/Rename/Delete X?](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/congyiw/2011/10/20/tfs-version-control-permissions-why-cant-i-branchrenamedelete-x/)

[image]

Comment: Thank you for the URL, as i mentioned in my post the user is now part of the PRoject Administrators group, this group has all version control permissions for all visible files and folders. Running the tf permissions command shows a few files with Inheritance of and group references to an old project, really strange. Also strange is that i cannot see these files myself, also not when logged in as project collection administrator. How should we fix the permissions on object we cannot see or dont exist ?

Comment: @Nico It sounds a bit complex, in TFS `deny` always overwrite `allow` if the user/group have multiple permission settings. So, you can try to set `Allow` explicitly for the specific Inherited user/group. Then try it again.

Comment: Yes i know that, we only have 1 Deny rule and the user is not part of that group. I think the problem is that there are appearently files listed by tf permissions that i cannot see in the UI. How should i modify those ?

Comment: @Nico No any experience on this, but you can try using the commands [tf permission](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/tfvc/permission-command?view=vsts) or [tfssecurity](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/tfs-server/command-line/tfssecurity-cmd?view=vsts) to explicitly grant the permission again even though you have already set `Allow` before.  BTW, what about other branches? Does this issue only occur on the specific branch?

Comment: It looks like the issue has been resolved. Using tf permission we went through the list and notice that there were some wrong group assignments from other projects. For now i added the user to that group in the other project and that seems to fix it, we need to get rid of these permission assignments later.